# Finding expression for probability given its PGF

Tags: probability

Consider the probability generating function for a random variable $X$:

$\varphi_X(s)=\dfrac{7-3s}{15-14s+3s^2}$

> Find an expression for $P(X=k)$, for $k\in\mathbb{N}$

My attempt was to break this expression down into a sum via partial fraction decomposition but I wasn't sure where to go from there?

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to add in the actual question! It's there now.

Comment: Is the question P(X = any natural number) or P(X =  any given natural number)?

Comment: The question has "$P(X=k)$ for $k=0,1,,\ldots$"

Comment: "My attempt was to break this expression down into a sum via partial fraction decomposition" Good idea, how did it go?

Comment: @Did: I got $\dfrac{A(3s-5)}{(s-3)(3s-5)}+\dfrac{B(s-3)}{(3s-5)(s-3)}$, where $A=-1/2, B=-3/2$

Comment: Right, so for example, what is the expansion of $\frac{A}{s-3}$ as a power series in $s$?

Comment: I'm not sure... I've never talked about power series before.

Comment: @Uchu How was the concept of PGF introduced to you? (this will definitely help understand the tools that can be used -- I would have assumed that PGF's are always introduced as power series).

Comment: Oh, I just looked it up. I knew it was defined as a series, but did not realize that it was called a **power series**

Comment: @Uchu If you stonewall attempts to know what you know, this will not go very far...

Answer (score 0):

You say you have obtained:
$\varphi_X(s)=\dfrac{7-3s}{15-14s+3s^2} = \dfrac{-1}{2(s-3)}+\dfrac{-3}{2(3s - 5)} $

Find $A, B$, then obtain the $k$-th derivative using: $\dfrac{\mathrm d^k ~~}{(\mathrm d s)^{k}}\dfrac 1{(as+b)} = \dfrac{k!\; (-a)^k }{(as+b)^{(1+k)}}$

So $\varphi_X^{(k)}(s)= \dfrac{k!\,(-1)^{k+1}}{2(s-3)^{k+1}}+\dfrac{k!\,(-3)^{k+1}}{2(3s - 5)^{k+1}}$

From there it's plain sailing since $\mathsf P(X=k) = \dfrac{\varphi_X^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$

Comment: What are the $a's$ and $b's$ in your answer? I want to say $A=a$ and $B=b$, but I am not sure.

Comment: @Ucho, general form; substitute values as required for the specific.